# Cakephp find inside a foreach

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

i have a model called Post and another one called Comment and on Comment i have a field called post_id... Post has many comments and Comment belongs to post.

I want list posts and the comments bellow, in pure php will be something like that:

```
<?php
foreach ($posts as $post){

 echo "<h3>" .$post['title']. "</h3>";

 $sel = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id =". $post['id']);
 $comments = mysql_fetcha_assoc($sel);

 foreach ($comments as $comment){
  echo "<p>" .$comment['comment']. "<p>";
 }
}
?>
```

I am using cake 2.x .. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your PostsController, set a variable `$posts` with `find(‘all’)` query to return an object containing all posts and records relating to the `Post` model, your method may look something like:

*PostsController:*

```
public function view() {
    if (!$this->Post->exists()) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
    }

    $this->set('posts', $this->Post->find('all'));
}
```

Then in your view, just iterate over $posts to display the title and related comments.

*Posts/view.ctp:*

```
<?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?>
    <h3><?php echo $post['Post']['title']; ?></h3>
    <?php foreach ($post['Comment'] as $comment):?>
        <p><?php echo $comment['comment'];?></p>
    <?php endforeach;?>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

See [Retrieving your data](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html) and [Additional methods and properties](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/additional-methods-and-properties.html#model-exists-id)

*From the documentation:*

> If the id is not provided with exists(), it calls Model::getID() to
>   obtain the current record id to verify, and then performs a
>   Model::find('count') on the currently configured datasource to
>   ascertain the existence of the record in persistent storage.

You should always have some sort of exception thrown if no records exist in the database.

Comment: bro your asnwear was cools but is not that i want.. i will list all posts at the same place, i wont pass $id.. i will list all post and show all comments inside each post.. my code in php explain thats better.. will be something like that... post 1 <br> loop comments post1 <br> post 2 <br> loop comments post 2.. etc..

Comment: Well in that case, just replace the find('first') query with find('all') and remove the id parameters, I just edited my answer to reflect find('all'), pretty simple stuff.. it's right in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to say but as above code is wrong way to fetch data from database in cakephp

As i assume your relation between model is perfect

so you can get from simple `find()` query like

```
$this->set('post', $this->Post->find('first', array(
  'conditions'=>array('Post.id'=>$id),
  'contain'=>array('Comment')
)));
```

that will give you output in view like

```
Array
(
    [Post] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [title] => The title
            [body] => This is the post body.
            [created] => 2007-12-28 13:54:34
            [modified] => 
        )
    [Comment] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [post_id] => 1
                    [name] => James
                    [email] => info@jamesfairhurst.co.uk
                    [text] => This is a sample comment.
                    [created] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [post_id] => 1
                    [name] => James
                    [email] => info@jamesfairhurst.co.uk
                    [text] => This is another sample comment.
                    [created] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                )
        )
)
```

let me know if i can assist you more..

Comment: "Contain" will only work if the containable behavior is used, The "Comment" array will be returned regardless.